# Why is there 3D before quotation mark(") in every HTML tag of the HTML emails I receive?

Tags: html, email, gmail, quotations

Have a look at some of the elements of the HTML emails I receive:

```
<img height=3D"1" width=3D"1" alt=3D"" src=3D"http://some-link.com">
<a style=3D"border:0px" href=3D"http://another-link.com">click here.<a>
```

I want to know, why there is 3D before each Quotation mark(") in the HTML elements above.

I saw the raw version of some HTML emails I received in Gmail.